# Toggle all submenus off except the active one

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, slidetoggle, submenu

I'm using the following html code to show a navigation menu with submenus and the following jQuery code to toggle on/off submenus:

```js
var container = $('.nav-menu');

container.find('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  var _this = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  _this.next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  $activeUl = _this.parent('li');
  $parentsUl = $activeUl.parents('ul');
  $('ul.sub-menu', container).not($activeUl).slideUp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a class="toggle" href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">Item 1.1</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Item 1.2</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Item 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a class="toggle" href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">Item 2.1</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Item 2.2</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Item 2.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a class="toggle" href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">Item 3.1</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Item 3.2</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Item 3.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When clicking a toggle link, I want my code to open its corresponding submenu and close all the other already opened submenus, but I can't make it work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the line `$activeUl = _this.parent('li')`, you are selecting the parent `li` element, and then you are trying to negate it from being selected `.not($activeUl)`.

This doesn't work because the parent element isn't being toggled. You should negate the sibling `ul` instead:

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nh8momjL/)

```
$container.find('.toggle').click(function (e) {
    var $menu = $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    $('ul.sub-menu', $container).not($menu).slideUp();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Oops! What a mistake! Thanks!

Comment: Just another question. If I have a submenu inside a submenu, how can I target it in the `not` function in `$('ul.sub-menu', $container).not($menu).slideUp()`. Am I making myself clear?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use **.not()**

```
container.find('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    $('.sub-menu').not(_this.next('.sub-menu')).slideUp();
    _this.next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/umehyrza/8/)